# How to efficiently display RSS feed items from thousdans of different sources

Tags: plugins, rss, feed, fatal-error, memory

I have looked around and there's a lot of static revolving around using RSS feeds so I haven't been able to find a straight answer.

I am working on a website that pulls information from pubmed.org. This website has ~6200 rare diseases. Each rare disease is a custom post with some specific content and metadata relating to that disease. Each disaese post is a page with the disease title, some info on it, other names for it, etc.

What I am trying got do is set up a widget that shows the latest 5 research publication relating to that specific disease. There will also be a Research page which will show all recent (paginated) disease publication which the user can search through. There will also be a page for each feed source that shows all of the latest research relating to the specific disease.

I tried to use fetch_feed and this slowed the page down too much (sometimes 30 seconds of page load). I now have WP RSS Feed Aggregator installed. I have one feed source for each disease and each feed source pulls in a maximum of 100 items. This means I currently have ~157,000 feed items. I am displaying the latest 5 research articles by using the shortcode [wp-rss-aggregator feeds="DISEASE-NAME-HERE"] and the feed items show up, but I still have the problem of a very slow load time, and some diseases even have a "fatal error: memory size of Bytes exhausted".

Here is my code for reference:

```
            $feed_title = sanitize_title($feed_title);
            $feed_title = strtolower($feed_title);
            $feed_title = str_replace(' ', '-', $feed_title);
            $shortcode = sprintf(
                '[wp-rss-aggregator feeds="%1$s"  template="sidebar" limit="5"]',
                $feed_title
                );
            if(!$ready){
            echo '<br/> feed title: ' . $feed_title . '<br/>';
            echo $shortcode . '<br/>';
            }
            
            if($ready){
                echo '<div class="container-fluid sidebar-widget">';
                echo '<div class="page-entry-header"><h3 class="home-page-title">Related Research</h3></div>';
                echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
                echo '</div>';
            }
```

is the slowness to be expected with this large number of feeds? I couldn't find an API reference to do the same thing I need. I've tried using W3 cache and to select cache feeds through WP RSS feed aggregator as well. I haven't tried to set up a cron job and a custom database to store the feeds as I wasn't able to discern, from the WP RSS Feed Aggregator docs, how they are storing the feed items and if it would be a big enough difference to change methods now.

Any guidance is much appreciated, thank you for reading.